# Customizing Quote PDF template

Tags: pdf, quote

We are trying to use out of box quote PDF template.

We want to have 2 sections for line items for example 1 for services and another of products. Have any one done some thing like this?

I have tried looking into the documentations but cant seem to find anything. Just wanted see if anyone else had any success implementing something like this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create a custom HTML template that's linked from your quote page via a button to use to create your PDF. You can have the PDF display in a new window if you want which some find helps make it easier for them to save the finished document. One example of how to do this can be found at the following link: [Creating Professional PDF Documents with CSS and VisualForce](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Creating_Professional_PDF_Documents_with_CSS_and_Visualforce).

Not everyone pre-composes the entire page on the controller as they've shown in that example (I don't). If you don't expect to create multi-page documents, its not at all necessary. There are also ways of using CSS to overcome line break issues at print time. In your case, you might even want to have a separate template for services and for products provided the services aren't linked to your products.

Comment: The link expired :(

Comment: @ŁukaszKojzar Unfortunately it appears when Salesforce redid the Developer Community the Wiki that code was in was removed. Everything they wanted to keep was moved to GitHub but I wasn't able to locate it. If you're looking for pre-composition and pagination code, I may have some of that in my files to post. You'll likely find it in other answers here on SF.SE.